# Why redirect keeps changing address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rt/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rt/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

There is no [R], but it keeps changing address bar location.
It set redirect 302...

I need to change root folder to /rt/ folder, but without changing location in address bar.
I can't use anything beside .htaccess file...

I want users when visit:
http://domain.com/index.php

see

http://domain.com/index.php

but open http://domain.com/rt/index.php

This index.php is example file, I need this working for every file...
Without changing location in browser address bar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using `Alias`?

```
Alias / /rt
```

If not, make sure you have mod_proxy enabled, and try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rt/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rt/$1 [PL]
</IfModule>
```